# Using ArcMap add x y data, points are in wrong location

Tags: arcmap, csv, excel, xy, point

According to ArcGIS [esri](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011494) when I add a CSV with the "add XY" tool, *** "The tool automatically adopts the data frame’s coordinate system"***.  Since I'm importing a csv with no defined coordinate system, I would expect that importing a csv with only lat/long values and a name, that it would produce a data set of points in the origional dataframe's coordinate system at the lat and long given in the table.  That is not what's happening.
 I'm trying to add a CSV table or Excel file (tried both) of a list a radio sites around LA.  The project is NAD83, as I believe that's an FCC standard.  I'm trying to add the table using the ADD XY Data tool, placing the Longitude column in the X field and Latitude in the Y field ( Fig 1).  On the map the points end up half way to Hawaii however.  If you look at the identities window (Fig 2),  you'll see that my lat/longs in the identities table don't match the locations.  For example "Avalon" has a lat of 33.34101 in the table, but 27.196035, and the long is about 20 degrees off also (See green and orange circled values in Fig 2).  In my table below, there are only those values, where you can see where the lat and long values are coming from.  I've also tried a table where i removed the hyper link column, but the result is the same.  Also (fig 4), shows my layer properties for my point data feature.
Does anyone have idea what's going on?
Im thinking the CSV file I'm bringing in has no projection defined.  I would think the lat and long should just line up to the project coordinates.
.

[image: Fig 1]
Fig 1

[image: Fig 2]
Fig 2

[image: Fig 3]
Fig 3

[image]
Fig 4

Comment: You're defining a projected coordinate system, but using geographic coordinates. Keep in mind that there are an infinite number of NAD83 projections -- You need to choose the right one (GCS_NAD_1983)

Comment: AKA type 4269 in the search box on the coordinate systems panel after clicking Edit on the Add XY Data UI.

Comment: OK.  I'm pretty new to this.  But why , if you look at Figure 2, does the attributes in the files lat long not match?  I'm importing a CSV with no projection information, just lat and longs.  If I put them in manually in the "go to XY" tool those lat longs take me to the corect place on the map.

Comment: The lat/long in the dialog box in Fig 2. is the location where you clicked, not where the feature is.

Comment: Fig 2 is the output of the identify tool. I clicked on the symbols of where those sites are.  Thats why the sites sand their attributes show up on the output of Fig 2.

Comment: @Frank The tool does as it says: it considers the coordinates in the CSV to be in the same coordinate system as the dataframe. It doesn't say it will read lat-long and reproject. As it stand in your example, all coordinates are between -180 and +180 **feet** - not degrees -  from the central meridian of State Plate California